# How to retrieve customers by email in node.js (Stripe)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, email, stripe-payments

I have this:

```
const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(
  'info@myemail.com'
);
```

I'm trying to get the customer number (id) of the customer based on the email address. Is this possible through stripe? It gives me an error when I do this.

Comment: it says you need the id https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve

Comment: maybe there can be many accounts for one email address

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list and it will return a list of customers with that particular email address.

```
const customers = await stripe.customers.list({
  email: 'info@myemail.com',
});
```

Note that there is a [limit](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list#list_customers-limit) on the number of objects to be returned. You should make use of [auto pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto) in case there is a large number of customers with the same email.

Comment: thank you. life saver!

Comment: What can I do in the case this email is saved as Info@myemail.com (capital i) in Stripe? Some ideas?

Comment: You can pass in `email: 'Info@myemail.com',`. The filter for `email` is case-sensitive - https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list?lang=curl#list_customers-email.

Answer (score 2):

Using [**"list()"**](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list?lang=node) and [**"search()"**](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/search?lang=node), you can get **customers** by **email** with these **Node.js code** below:

```js
const customers = await stripe.customers.list({
  email:"info@myemail.com",
});
```

```js
const customers = await stripe.customers.search({
  query:"email:'info@myemail.com'",
});
```

You can also limit customers to get with **"limit" parameter** as shown below:

```js
const customers = await stripe.customers.list({
  email:"info@myemail.com",
  limit: 3,
});
```

```js
const customers = await stripe.customers.search({
  query:"email:'info@myemail.com'",
  limit: 3,
});
```

Comment: From docs about search method: Don’t use search in read-after-write flows where strict consistency is necessary. Under normal operating conditions, data is searchable in less than a minute. Occasionally, propagation of new or updated data can be up to an hour behind during outages. 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/search